# Syntax Error in SQL in Table Creation Code (i don't see an error...)

Tags: mysql, ddl

I'm getting a Syntax Error in the following Test-SQL-Code at 'CREATE TABLE ORDER(':

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENT(
    CLIENT_ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    STREET_ADDRESS VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    APARTMENT_NUMBER VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CITY VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ZIP_CODE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ORDER(
    ORDER_ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    CLIENT_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    DATE_ORDERED BIGINT NOT NULL,
    SUM FLOAT NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

order is a keyword better to not use it but if needed then use double quote

```
CREATE TABLE "ORDER"(
    ORDER_ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    CLIENT_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    DATE_ORDERED BIGINT NOT NULL,
    SUM FLOAT NOT NULL
);
```